# Is there some example to create ngrx/Store on Angular 7 in one command

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, store, ngrx

I am creating new web Dashboard and using ngrx/store for loading and data in Angular 7. For about third time i am creating and generating files for different store interface and it seams that it will not stop here. So i wonder is there some cli bundle to create store for module in one commnad line.

I am using cli as best to create  action,effects,reducer,state every time. I was try some solutions from cli but its create only reducer and index.ts.

```
npm install @ngrx/schematics --save-dev
npm install @ngrx/{store,effects,entity,store-devtools} --save
ng config cli.defaultCollection @ngrx/schematics
ng generate @ngrx/schematics:store State --root --module some-app.module.ts -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `ng update` commands, for example https://ngrx.io/guide/store/install#installing-with-ng-add

```
ng add @ngrx/store
```

This will install `@ngrx/store` and do a minimal scaffold to get you started.

Comment: thank you,. but i don't have problem to install it, i already using store and i create store and ngrx. Problem is that i create store bundle files (effect,store,action,reducer) too many times. And i wonder is there some CLI with parameters like
ng generate @ngrx/schematics:store MyStore --root --module some-app.module.ts -d --action --effects --state --selectors or something like that

Comment: I think there is no such command in one line to generate all those actions, effects etc. You need to use individual commands. Refer https://ngrx.io/guide/schematics documentation.